# connect to ubuntu vm file file share from windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

I just recently made the switch from Mac Yosemite to Windows 10. I transferred my VM successfully and updated my Windows hosts file so that on my Windows machine I can enter mysite.local in google chrome and successfully reach my /var/www/ directory on my Ubuntu VM.

I'm looking to reach my "Share" folder on my Ubuntu from Windows. To do this on my Mac I would open a finder window and use the Apple-K shortcut which "Connect to Server" and I would enter smb://mysite.local [Just like this](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/osx/yos_connect_to_server.png) and it would take me to my "share" folder on Ubuntu which I already I already have set to a dir of my liking.

I'm looking for the equivalent of that so that process on Windows.

Comment: Usually on Windows this is `\\hostname\sharename`

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out this morning after hours of googling around. I was searching for the wrong keywords in my search. You are correct and I appreciate the response. I also think that it is valid to add for anyone else who runs into the same problem in the future that you can reach this resolution by clicking on - file explorer>right click on network>map network drive.